# How refactor the names of my contexts in my tests in Rspec-Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

How I should write the names of my contexts for my tests ?

I have a user with roles : user and admin

My User model has a column 'banned' : true or false

I want to test all possible cases

[image: name of my 'contexts']

thanks!

Comment: Does `banned` behavior depend on the user role?

Comment: @slowjack2k mmmm, no

Comment: So it can be a toplevel context and doesn't need to be nested within user context.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's ok what are you doing... But, if you want to reuse some specs, you can use:

- [shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples)
- [custom matchers](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-5/docs/custom-matchers/define-a-custom-matcher)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like:

```
describe 'GET #index' do

  context 'admin user' do
    scenario 'is blocked' do
      # your test
    end

    scenario 'is not blocked' do
      # your test
    end
  end

  context 'regular user' do
    scenario 'is blocked' do
      # your test
    end

    scenario 'is not blocked' do
      # your test
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what is the difference between 'scenario' and 'context'?

Comment: The 'scenario' DSL corresponds to 'it'. It's simply an alias that allows feature specs to read as an acceptance test. I think this is more readable than the one you currently have, and you only set the context once per user type (admin / regular user)